# SOLR, SQL how to present nested JSON data?

Tags: json, indexing, solr, nested

I would like to understand how to work and present a nested JSON data.

If I have a JSON like :

```
{
    "name": "John"
     ,"address":
     {
       "street" : "st. Yanica"
         ,"city" : "Moscow"
     }
 }
```

How I can configure the JSON in schema.xml in order to integrate it in SOLR and in order to obtain a response having the same presentation.
The data are coming from database and I would like to present them as the JSON here above so that when a search is done, the response contain the adress with the fields street and city nested under address :

```
{
    "name": "John"
     ,"address":
     {
       "street" : "st. Yanica"
         ,"city" : "Moscow"
     }
 }
```

Thanks

Comment: In general, try to avoid having parent/child-relationships if possible. Flatten the document to `address_street´ and `address_city`. This will make everything much simpler. Otherwise - IF you _must_ have them because of certain matching issues, look at [blockjoins and nested documents](http://yonik.com/solr-nested-objects/).

Comment: Thanks, I will do like you suggest

Comment: Actually I try to implement solution with nested documents, but I do not succes to make somethnig working. I have a lot of data and I would like to groupe them into the response in order to have more visibility. Do you have an example for schema and data-config.xml ?

Comment: Is there another solution by using group or facet

Comment: I have _no_ idea what you're trying to from your explanation. Sorry. Please ask a question or update this one and ping me with all the details about what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sorry, I update my question, hope it i more clear. I would like to obtain a response after calling SOLR which group the address data so the JSON is more lisible.